# How can I add new implementation?

Tags: java, arrays, oop, inheritance

I have two classes. The first is the main one, the second is its implementation.

**first**

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class DecrementingCarousel {
    int capacity;
    static int[] elements;
    int size = 0;
    boolean called;

    public DecrementingCarousel(int capacity) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
        elements = new int[capacity];
    }

    public boolean addElement(int element) {
        if (element <= 0 || elements.length == size) {
            return false;
        }
        elements[size++] = element;
        return true;
    }


    public CarouselRun run() {
        if (!called) {
            elements = Arrays.copyOf(elements, size);
            called = true;
            return new CarouselRun();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**second**

```
public class CarouselRun {
    int count = 0;
    int[] array = DecrementingCarousel.elements;

    public int next() {
        if (array.length == 0) {
            return -1;
        }

        if (count == array.length) {
            count = 0;
        }

        while (array[count] == 0) {
            count++;

            if (count > array.length - 1) {
                count = 0;
            }

            if (isFinished()) {
                return -1;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] == -1) {
                break;
            }
        }

        count++;
        action(count - 1);
        return array[count - 1] + 1;
    }

    public boolean isFinished() {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            sum += array[i];
        }
        
        return sum == 0;
    }

    public void action(int index) {
        array[index]--;
    }
}
```

Then I have a new class, let's call it "HalvingCarousel" which extends our first class:

```
public class HalvingCarousel extends DecrementingCarousel {

    public HalvingCarousel(final int capacity) {
        super(capacity);
    }
    
}
```

what I should to do so that it does not reduce the element by one but divides it by 2. Need to apply regular integer division, discarding the remainder. For example, 5 / 2 = 2.

Answer (score 0):

By seeing your code, it can be seen that `count` is type of `int`. So if you divide by two, you will get desired result:

```
int foo = 5 / 2;
System.out.println(foo); // 2
```

This is simple example of DividingCarousel:

```
public class DecrementingCarousel
{
    public int Capacity;

    public DecrementingCarousel(int capacity)
    {
        Capacity = capacity;
        Capacity -= 1;
    }
}
```

and:

```
public class DivideCarousel extends DecrementingCarousel
{
    public DivideCarousel(int capacity)
    {
        super(capacity);
        Capacity = capacity / 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but I need both classes to work based on the passed constructor. If I want to work with DecrementingCarousel that it should to return decrement by 1. If it's a HalvingCarousel - it should to return divide by 2

Comment: @yurkaishere please, see my updated answer

Comment: sorry i'm newbie on this site but i have already done it thank you for information :) about you answer: there is not a Java and i can't change initial classes i gues

Comment: @yurkaishere I''ve edited my code to be Java code. If you can not change initial classes then just do not call base classes. Please, see my updated code.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, but it doesn't work correctly :(

Comment: @yurkaishere could you elaborate what means `it doesn't work correctly`?

Comment: same output when i try to do it in Main method.
HalvingCarousel carousel = new HalvingCarousel(size) and DecrementingCarousel carousel = new DecrementingCarousel(size)